# How to pass tag values in cucumber test runner file from Jenkins?

Tags: cucumber

I have scenario where I want to run some tags in cucumber through jenkins, is there any way to create build parameters in Jenkins to pass tag values externally to test runners file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently using "run cucumber test" from cucumber-plugin as the build step to run the test? Or are you running your cucumber test by executing a shell script?

If you are executing a shell script, you can set up a parameter or environment variable in your Jenkins job as:

`CUCUMBER_TAG=@your_tag`

And add something like this to your shell in your build step:

`cucumber --tags $CUCUMBER_TAG`

Plugins such as [Environment Script](https://plugins.jenkins.io/environment-script) or [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) might help.

But if you are using some plugin to run your cucumber test, you may need to check their doc. We are currently using shell to run our test so I am not familiar to how to use those plugins.

In order to use a shell script as a build step in your Jenkins, you just need to add the "Execute shell" to your build section of your job. If you put everything in such structure:

```
+-- Jenkins job workspace
|   +-- features
|       +-- step_definition
|       +-- support
|       +-- feature files
```

The shell could just be:

```
cucumber --tags $CUCUMBER_TAG
```

Then you just need to install the plugins I recommend or the plugins similar to what I recommend and then add CUCUMBER_TAG with your tag values

Comment: Thanks, i did not use any shell script, I was doing some research if there is any solution, just to see can you help me in getting shell script

Comment: @khuddus I have edited my answer and added the brief instructions

Comment: Hi , which type of paramter should I select for cucumber_tag in jenkins

Comment: Thanks I will try it